The image of Gauss map of Hyperboloid
I am a bit confused with the image of Gauss map of Hyperboloid.
First, we can parametrize the surface by
$$ \mathbf{x}(u,v)= \left( \sqrt{1+u^2} \cos v , \sqrt{1+u^2}\sin v, u \right)$$
Then
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{x}_u = \left( \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \cos v , \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \sin v , 1 \right) \\
&\mathbf{x}_v = \left( -\sqrt{1+u^2} \sin v , \sqrt{1+u^2} \cos v , 0 \right)\\
&N = \frac{ \mathbf{x}_u \land \mathbf{x}_v }{ \vert \mathbf{x}_u \land \mathbf{x}_v \vert} = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+2u^2 }} \left( -\sqrt{1+u^2} \cos v , -\sqrt{1+u^2} \sin v , u \right)
\end{align*}
By using cylindrical coordinate system, the distance from $z$-axis(radius) is
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < \dfrac{ \sqrt{1+u^2}}{ \sqrt{1+2u^2}} \leq 1$$
and the $z$ component(height) is
$$ -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{1+2u^2}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Second, if we use consider the surface as a level set $f^{-1}(0)$ of $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1$,
\begin{align*}
f_x &= 2x ,\ f_y = 2y ,\ f_z = 2x \\
N(x,y,z) &= \frac{(f_x , f_y , f_z)}{\sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + f_z^2}}\\
&=\frac{ (x,y,-z) }{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}
\end{align*}
But then it is weird: $N$ can cover entire sphere.
It seems to be impossible by the shape of the graph $x^2 +y^2 -z^2 =1$.
Intuitively, I think it occurs due to the independency of the variables.
The variables of latter parametrization are not independent since they still have to satisfy $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$.
If I substitute this equation, I get
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 }} = \frac{ \sqrt{z^2 +1}}{\sqrt{2z^2 +1}} \leq 1 \\
&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < -\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +z^2}} = -\frac{z}{\sqrt{2z^2 +1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
which is the same result as the first method.
If my approach is appropriate, is it dangerous to use the definition
$$N(x,y,z) = \frac{(f_x , f_y , f_z)}{\sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + f_z^2}}$$
depending on the parametrization?
I am confused since my textbook do Carmo is using this definition without any caution.

Have you considered drawing some pictures? Since this is a surface of revolution, you can do your drawing in 2D. And how Are you reasoning that $N$ covers the whole sphere? Yes, you mean non-independence of the variables.

@TedShifrin Yes, actually I drew the shape of the surface and realized that $N$ cannot cover the whole sphere. Then, it may sound obvious, is the second definition of $N$ not completely true for some cases?

No, it’s fine (except for a possible minus sign on the whole thing). How is that formula related to the position vector of the point on the surface?
